# Wait until page is loaded after location.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following function in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.folder-action').bind('click', function location() {

        if(parent.document.location.pathname!="/home.php"){
            window.location.replace("home.php");
            location();
         });

         //Other portion of code that need page has been loaded.
     });
});
```

When the replace has been excecuted I need that all the elements of the page are already loaded to execute other portions of the code in the new page(home.php).
It've tryed with:

```
setTimeout(function() {location()}, 300);
```

But it still doesn't work. Is it possible to wait until all elements of the page are loaded?

Comment: move your if at the end?

Comment: jQuery bind is deprecated, use [on-function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: why don't you move the "portion of the code" that need to be loaded to the `home.php`, inside  the `$(document).read()` function there(home.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do it like that because once you used the **replace** function, the browser will leave your current page and won't execute anymore code.

The best thing to do is to put your Other portion of code in the `$(document).ready` of the home.php